# Delete multiple same value in listbox VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

how to remove all of the data in listbox. not clear there are other values just preferred to show this data only. just want to remove them all at once.

[image]

Comment: Clarify yourself. Do you want to remove items whose appearance is more than one?

Comment: `ListBox.Clear` or whatever the equivalent is in your controls.

Comment: the image that i attached is just a sample for raffle. it is multiply by their entries. what i want is that when their entry has been picked. just one entry. it'l remove all of their other entries. just like on the image. if that entry is picked i wanted to clear or remove them from listbox. my listbox is populated using database and it takes long if i do reload the listbox to update it.

Comment: Where are the items being added to the ListBox? It would probably be easier to avoid duplicates there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System

Public Class Form1

Private list As New List(Of Integer)()

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    list.Clear()

    list.Add(1)
    list.Add(2)
    list.Add(3)
    list.Add(3)
    list.Add(4)
    list.Add(4)
    list.Add(4)

    For Each value As Integer In list
        ListBox1.Items.Add(value)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    Dim distinct As List(Of Integer) = list.Distinct().ToList()

    For Each value As Integer In distinct
        ListBox1.Items.Add(value)
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```